# Smarty trying to echo the config item its not working

Tags: smarty

Smarty codeigniter3 print config item not working. I am trying to do the following thing

{$this->session->userdata('userid')}
{$this->config->item(base_url)}

I am getting this error,

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Call to a member function item() on a non-object

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a array as data in controller like this

```
public function myFunction()
{
   $data['base']=$this->config->item('base_url');
   $data['userid']=$this->session->userdata('userid');
   $this->smarty->view('yourview.tpl',$data);
}
```

then in your smarty page write this

```
{$userid}{$base}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.. but why i cannot use globally? I have used in ci2 its working but ci 3 giving error.. even i cannot call function like this {$this->test_model->testfun()}..

Comment: While introduce CI3 there are lot of change it may be one of them. If can solve your problem please verify it. It may help other those who face the same issue

Comment: I have tested the same code in codeigniter 2 its working. Even im not getting the uri segment {$this->uri->rsegment(1)} in ci3. Please help